# Déjà Dup Backups skips Steam directory

Tags: backup, steam, deja-dup, duplicity

I enabled periodic backups in Ubuntu 20.04 using Ubuntu's built-in Backups tool (Déjà Dup). I back-up my entire home directory and don't ignore any folders. Back-ups are executed every week.

Today I tried to restore my `~/.steam` directory, only to find out that:

```
$ duplicity --file-to-restore ~/.steam file:///media/Backups/saibot ~/.steam

Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Thu Apr 29 05:30:39 2021
home/serrano/.steam not found in archive - no files restored.
```

The `.steam` directory is not even backed-up. I verified this using:

```
$ duplicity list-current-files file:///media/Backups/saibot | grep -F .steam
```

But if I try to restore any other directory in my home directory, for example `~/.vim` or `~/Documents`, it works just fine.

Why is the `.steam` directory not being backed-up? Note that I don't specified any folders to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1562357) in Déjà Dup. I quote one of the developers comment on this bug here:

> This one is tricky because steamapps isn't the only content in that directory that we don't care about.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was unaware.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I had no idea of this "feature". This is really bad in my opinion; the user decides what to backup, not the developer.